# Module parse failed: Unexpected token (8:15), WebPack 5, React, Django

Tags: reactjs, django, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

So Im a noob to all of this and have been following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GieYIzvdt2U but for the life of me can not seem to get this to work. There are many related questions but despite my best efforts I have not been able to get past this error trying any of the existing solutions. When I run `npm run dev` I get the following

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (8:15)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See http
s://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| class App extends Component {
|     render() {
>         return <div>React APP</div>
|     }
| }
 @ ./GeoAnalyticsSite/frontend/src/index.js 1:0-35

webpack 5.47.0 compiled with 1 error in 69 ms
```

Here are all of my NPM dev dependencies and the scripts in my package json

```
{
...
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development ./GeoAnalyticsSite/frontend/src/index.js -o ./GeoAnalyticsSite/frontend/static/frontend/",
    "build": "webpack --mode production ./GeoAnalyticsSite/frontend/src/index.js -o ./GeoAnalyticsSite/frontend/static/frontend/,"
  },
...
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.8",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^5.47.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2"
  },
...
}
```

The error message makes it sound as if it is an issue with my webpack. Here are my babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react","env", "react"],
  "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
}
```

and my webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
          presets: [
            ['@babel/preset-env', "@babel/react"]
          ]
        }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Both are in the same directory. Here is the offending javascript file App.js to my understanding I have told webpack to search for the js and the jsx file extension so I'm confused as to why I still get the error message.

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div>React APP</div>
    }
}

ReactDom.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

As far as Django goes I have created a views.py for the front end

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'frontend/index.html')
```

urls.py for front end

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index)
]
```

linked things up at the top level urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('frontend.urls')),
    path('', include('GeoAnalytics.urls'))
]
```

and if it is helpful here is my settings.py apps as well

```
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'GeoAnalytics.apps.GeoanalyticsConfig',
    'frontend'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

I would really appreciate any help thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out it was something dumb in my case. If you see this error and feel your config is correct webpack will look for it in whatever directory you called npm init I think. I was careful to put the bablerc and webpack config in the same dir, but I was not carefull to put them both in the right dir. In my case they needed to be at the same level as my package.json